# Transfer image comments to new comments after image Compression

Tags: python, python-3.x, metadata, pyexiv2

Hello I'm working on some code where the image will be compress and transfer the comments from the old image to newly compress image. the compression works smoothly but the transfer of comments in the new image doesn't work and is not showing in the properties -> comments of the image.

I'm also using [pyexiv2] https://github.com/LeoHsiao1/pyexiv2 for the metadata read and write

On the first run it works fine but on the later runs the comments is not showing in the Image properties -> comments anymore. I've tried looking at the code maybe I just edited something accidentally but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```py
import glob2
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os
import pyexiv2


def getImgPaths():
    image_paths = glob2.glob('images/**/*.jpg')
    return image_paths

# ? copy metadata from original to new
def moveMetaData(base_image, new_image):

    print('***** Moving meta-data *****')

    i = pyexiv2.Image(base_image)

    meta_comment = i.read_exif()

    # ? print comment
    print("initial metacomment   : " + meta_comment["Exif.Photo.UserComment"]) 


    # ! encode comment to new image
    new_image_encode = pyexiv2.Image(new_image)
    #  print("New Image Initial Tags: " + str(new_image_encode))

    new_image_encode.modify_exif(
        {"Exif.Photo.UserComment": meta_comment["Exif.Photo.UserComment"]}) 


    o = new_image_encode.read_exif()

    print("Inserted Comment to new image   : " + o["Exif.Photo.UserComment"]) 


def compressImage(image_path):
    im = Image.open(image_path)
    image_name = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(image_path))
    print('Input file size   : ', im.size)
    print('Input file name   : ', image_name)
    print('Input Image Size  : ', os.path.getsize(image_path))

    out_parent_dir = os.path.join('out', image_path.split(image_name)[0])
    print(out_parent_dir)

    newpath = os.path.join('out', image_path)

    if not os.path.exists(out_parent_dir):
        os.makedirs(out_parent_dir)

    im.save(os.path.join(out_parent_dir, image_name),
            optimize=True, quality=50)

    print('Success ' + image_path)

    # ? copy metadata to new image
    moveMetaData(image_path, newpath)



print('***** Compression Started *****')

for image_path in getImgPaths():
    try:
        compressImage(image_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        with open('logs/errors.txt', 'a') as fh:
            print(str(e) + " : " + str(image_path), file=fh)
        pass


print('***** Compression Ended *****')
```

Comment: What one program calls a metadata field may not be what another program calls it.  Or it may fill the property from multiple locations.  You don't mention what OS you are using to look at the properties but Windows takes the Comment property from three different tags.  You are copying from the `EXIF:UserComment` tag, but Windows will also use the `XMP:UserComment` tag (rarely used) and the `XPComment` tag, which is the most likely source for your comment.

Comment: Thank you, I converted the UserComment into ascii and insert it as an XPComment